# How do i add "imported files" for python script in setup.py file?

Tags: python, python-import, setup.py

I have two files - `command-cli` and `myLib.py`. I imported `myLib.py` in `command-cli` and use functions from `myLib.py` in `command-cli`.
How can I add `myLib.py` to `setup.py` file to use it as a library with functions for `command-cli`? Now I added it to setup.py file this way:  `scripts=['command-cli', 'myLib.py'])`, all works good, but after installing the package, if I start typing `myLib` and press `Tab` for autocomplete, I can see `myLib.py` suggestion. This looks not correct because I don't want to use myLib.py as a command, only as lib file.

**command-cli file:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import myLib

myLib.a()
```

**myLib.py file:**

```
def a():
    print("Hello, I`m working now, all fine")
```

**setup.py file:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='command-cli',
        version='1.0',
        description='My command',
        author='gyok',
        author_email='gyok',
        scripts=['command-cli', 'myLib.py'])
```

Comment: can you please provide your code?

Comment: Provided code, thank you

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about what your goal is here, could you please try to clarify your question? Could you just write "import myLib" at the top of setup.py?

Comment: My goal is to use functions in script `command-cli` from another file. With setup.py file, I provided I can do this, but `myLib.py` also becomes a script-command. I don`t want use myLib.py as a command(if I run myLib.py, I will get nothing). I tried just write "import myLib" in setup.py file and got this error message:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/command-cli", line 4, in <module>
    myLib.a()
NameError: name 'myLib' is not defined
**

Comment: [This guide might help](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html).

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? I am facing this issue as well.